# How to append content from one element to another on hover event

Tags: jquery, events, dom

So I have four links with titles that I want to get the attribute values from and append to an external, empty div.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGhY/3/)

The part I'm having problems with is the javascript

```
$('li a.link').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).text().appendTo('.container');
    });
```

I don't care if I grab the attribute value or the text inside, but neither seems to work.  I've gotten the empty div to say "Hello World!" when I hover over the links, but I can't get it to grab either the Title value or the text within the HTML and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that if this is a hover even you'd also want the text to disappear on mouseleave of the "Li a" so I made you a jsFiddle example to do both. Please check it out and if any questions feel free to ask.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','li a',function(){
    $('.container').text($(this).attr('title'));
}).on('mouseleave','li a', function(){
    $('.container').text('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danieljordan13/JfGhY/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li a.link').hover(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.container').append(title);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/JfGhY/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, if you want to append the text:

```
$('li a').hover(
    function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $('.container').text(function(i,t){
            return t + ' ' + text;
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JfGhY/4/).

Or, if you want to replace the text:

```
$('li a').hover(
    function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $('.container').text(text);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JfGhY/6/).

Having re-read the question, and seen you want to use the `title` attributes, I'd suggest, instead:

```
$('li a').hover(
    function(){
        var title = this.title;
        $('.container').text(title);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JfGhY/8/).

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `append()` before `appendTo()`

This works:

```
$('.container').append($(this).text());
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JfGhY/5/

To append the title:

```
$('.container').append($(this).attr('title'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGhY/10/